# How to measure component voltage?

Tags: led, components, voltage

I want to know the voltage (tension) of every of my components. I have leds, a buzzer, a piezo, a photoresistor, a rain sensor and more.

**I have a multimeter and I would like to use it to measure the voltage of the components.** I know how to measure current and resistance but not voltage yet.

I want to start measuring the leds. I know they are around 2 volts, but I want to measure them exactly with a multimeter.

This is my multimeter:
[image: Multimeter]

Comment: "tension" sounds like a mistranslation. Tension is what happens if you pull on something. It's a physical force and not something one really cares about when doing electric..

Comment: Tension (English) = Tensione (Italian) = Voltage (English). And an other one: Tension (English) = Tensión (Spanish) = Voltage (English). There are many more, for example: Tension (English) = Spannung (German) = Voltage (English). That multimeter is one of the cheapest multimeters there is, I paid less than 2 dollars for it. If you want to measure voltage, put the black wire in "COM", the red wire in "VΩmA" and turn the dial to a range in the DCV, try to measure the voltage of a battery.

Comment: I am going to buy a Fluke multimeter, but I have to decide which model to buy (there is a lot).

Comment: @Jot You can add Swedish to the list too and perhaps mention British high tention overhead lines for electricity distribution.

Comment: Don't buy a Fluke multimeter UNTIL you can use that one properly ie all its functions...

Comment: Are these components already in a powered circuit? Their voltage will be exactly zero, if not. Also, the voltage you measure across the photoresistor will vary depending on how cloudy it is outside your window!

Comment: I have one of those meters, they gave it to me free with a $10 purchase, but it works just fine. one nice thing about it is that you can measure small currents and voltage w/o swapping lead plugs. that good since you don't have many swaps before the connectors wear away...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only measure the voltage of a device that generates a voltage (such as a battery).

Some devices, like LEDs, have a fixed voltage at which they operate, and for that you can pass a fixed current through it within the specifications and measure the voltage *dropped* across it.

Similar for other devices - have them working in a circuit and measure the voltage dropped across it - however that isn't the specified voltage, only the voltage it is running at for that specific scenario.

To find out the voltage *limit* you instead need to consult the datasheet for the device. That will tell you all you need to know.